# How to use vector::push_back()` with a struct?

Tags: c++, vector

How can I `push_back` a `struct` into a vector?

```
struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

std::vector<point> a;

a.push_back( ??? );
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
point mypoint = {0, 1};
a.push_back(mypoint);
```

Or if you're allowed, give `point` a constructor, so that you can use a temporary:

```
a.push_back(point(0,1));
```

Some people will object if you put a constructor in a class declared with `struct`, and it makes it non-POD, and maybe you aren't in control of the definition of `point`. So this option might not be available to you. However, you can write a function which provides the same convenience:

```
point make_point(int x, int y) {
    point mypoint = {x, y};
    return mypoint;
}

a.push_back(make_point(0, 1));
```

Comment: how does make_point function work, will the local var mypoint be not out of scope after the return?

Comment: Would'nt `emplace_back` be better?

Comment: @ThePunisher: definitely, but the question was asked 7 years ago about `push_back`, so I wasn't going to give a non-standard answer that the questioner's implementation may or may not have implemented yet :-)

Comment: If you have a constructor you should probably use `emplace_back()` instead of `push_back()`.

Answer (score 15):

```
point p;
p.x = 1;
p.y = 2;

a.push_back(p);
```

Note that, since `a` is a vector of points (not pointers to them), the push_back will create a copy of your point struct -- so `p` can safely be destroyed once it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 11):

```
struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

vector <point> a;

a.push_back( {6,7} );
a.push_back( {5,8} );
```

Use the curly bracket.

Comment: This is nice, but how does emplace_back() compares to this, is it better in some way?

Comment: @bbv You need a constructor for emplace_back(). Doing it like Rewd0n should however invoke the move variant of push_back, so the end result is pretty much the same.

Comment: This didn't work on my compiler (Apple LLVM)

Answer (score 1):

```
point foo; //initialize with whatever
a.push_back(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

We should use emplace_back() for user defined data types such as structs.We can use it even with primitive data types as well.