# In place creation of custom type object in std::list

Tags: c++, stl, std

Let's say I have a struct

```
struct someStruct
{
    int a;
    customType b;
};
```

and an `std::list` of `someStruct` instances

```
std::list<someStruct> aList;
```

One way of storing items to that list is by creating an instance of
`someStruct`, store the values I want to that instance and then store
the instance in the list like that

```
someStruct obj;
obj.a = 4;
obj.b = customType::value_type;
aList.push_back(obj);
```

Is there a more generic way of doing this so that I don't need to create an object?

Sorry for using an array as example at first!

Comment: anArray[0].a = 4; anArray[0].b = 6; // etc

Comment: Oh yes off course! I was thinking of having a struct with custom data types that c++ doesn't by default know how to construct, but i just realized that as long as I provide the constructor c++ will know how to handle it.
Should I remove the question?

Comment: Worth noting that when you create an array in C++, the default constructor will be called for each element. So you can't create an array of a type that doesn't have a default constructor.

Comment: @zenith Yes you can.

Comment: @zenith http://ideone.com/gMn2Ld

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited because the original question changed:**

Since this is now explicitly C++, the one-liner way to do this is to provide a constructor for the struct.

```
struct someStruct {
  someStruct(int new_a, customType new_b) : a(new_a), b(new_b) {}
  int a;
  customType b;
};

...

aList.push_back(someStruct(4, customType::value_type));
```

This is closely related to [push_back() a struct into a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289597/push-back-a-struct-into-a-vector)

Answer (score 3):

In C++11 you can do

```
anArray[0] = {123, 456};
```

Or more verbosely:

```
anArray[0] = someStruct{123, 456};
```

And in any version of C++ you can perform aggregate array initialization:

```
someStruct anArray[10] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, /*...*/};
```

Answer (score 2):

In C you can use the [*designated initializer*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) syntax:

```
struct someStruct ss[] = {
    {.a=5, .b=6}
,   {.a=6, .b=7}
,   {.a=7, .b=8}
};
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/WICYoD)

This syntax is not available in C++, so you have to stick to the old-style initialization based on positions:

```
struct someStruct ss[] = {
    {5, 6}
,   {6, 7}
,   {7, 8}
};
```