# Read data from a file in vector

Tags: c++, vector, fstream

My task is to read this data from a file into a vector:

```
21000 Landhau Nolte brown
19000 Modern_fit Hoeffner magnolie
14700 Pure_Style Wellmann black
```

This is my attempt, but push back isn't working. I already looked at some examples here at Stack Overflow, but somehow it's not working.

`functions.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct Kitchen {
    double price;
    string name;
    string manufacturer;
    string color;
};
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "functions.h"

int main(){

    vector<Kitchen> Kitchens;

    fstream myFile;
    myFile.open("kitchen.txt", ios::in);
    if (myFile.is_open()) {
        while (!myFile.eof()) {
            double price;
            string name;
            string manufacturer;
            string color;
            myFile >> price >> name >> manufacturer >> color;
            Kitchens.push_back(price, name, manufacturer, color);

        }

        myFile.close();
    }
    else cout << "not opened." << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please explain exactly what's the current behavior instead of just _It's not working_ (what's the compiler error message?), and show a [mcve] consists of example input/output.

Comment: [Possible dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289597/push-back-a-struct-into-a-vector)?

Comment: Unrelated: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: it is rather unlikely that `push_back` is broken. You should explain why it isnt working

Comment: (in this case, it happens that the input doesn't matter, then you don't need to open a file and read input, they're not required in a [mcve] anyway)

Comment: @mooncrater Instead of leaving "Thanks" comment, you can just accept answers. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.  It's especially pernicious in header files, as you now inflict the problem on every source file that includes the header!

Answer (score 2):

structure is an aggregate type but for pushing struct object into vector of struct, you have to create one even though it can be temporary :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct Kitchen {
    double price;
    string name;
    string manufacturer;
    string color;
};
int main() {
  std::vector<Kitchen> kt;
  kt.push_back(Kitchen{21000,"Landhau","Nolte","brown"});

 return 0;
}
```

Also with minor modification and having a parameterized constructor in your Kitchen struct you can avoid internal copying/moving operation of push_back and directly use emplace_back.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct Kitchen {
    double price;
    string name;
    string manufacturer;
    string color;
    Kitchen(double p,
            const string& n,
            const string &m,
            const string &c):price(p),name(n),manufacturer(m),color(c) {}
};
int main(){

    vector<Kitchen> Kitchens;

    fstream myFile;
    myFile.open("kitchen.txt", ios::in);
    if (myFile.is_open()) {
        while (!myFile.eof()) {
            double price;
            string name;
            string manufacturer;
            string color;
            myFile >> price >> name >> manufacturer >> color;
            Kitchens.emplace_back(price, name, manufacturer, color);

        }

        myFile.close();
    }
    else cout << "not opened." << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: With Aggregate initialization that is shown with push_back scenario we need to create temporary that will be moved and with this constructor approach object will be created in place inside vector

Comment: This will not compile check here : https://repl.it/repls/PhysicalFrivolousOctagon

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing wrong is trying to pass 4 random variables to a `push_back` that actually only takes one, and that one is of the value type of the vector.

```
Kitchen k; 
myFile >> k.price >> k.name >> k.manufacturer >> k.color;
Kitchens.push_back(k);
```

Answer (score 1):

`push_back` takes a `Kitchen`. The code is providing pieces of a `Kitchen`. Give `emplace_back` a try or instantiate a temporary `Kitchen` to pass into `push_back`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do this properly.

Starting with the header, don't include more than needed for the definitions in that header, and don't import all identifiers from `std` into the global namespace.

```
#include <string>

struct Kitchen {
    double price;
    std::string name;
    std::string manufacturer;
    std::string color;

    Kitchen(double price, std::string name,
            std::string manufacturer, std::string color)
        : price{price}, name{name}, manufacturer{manufacturer}, color{color}
    {}
};
```

I've added a simple constructor, as we'll need that for `emplace_back` later.

Now implement the `main()`.  For a reproducible example, it's better to read from a string stream than to have to mess about with files:

```
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<Kitchen> kitchens;

    std::istringstream file("21000 Landhau Nolte brown\n"
                            "19000 Modern_fit Hoeffner magnolie\n"
                            "14700 Pure_Style Wellmann black\n");

    {
            double price;
            std::string name;
            std::string manufacturer;
            std::string color;
            while (file >> price >> name >> manufacturer >> color) {
                kitchens.emplace_back(price, name, manufacturer, color);
            }
    }

    std::clog << "Read " << kitchens.size() << " kitchens from input\n";
}
```

Note here that `!eof()` doesn't guarantee that a read will succeed.  Instead, we attempt the read, and then test whether the input stream is in a failure state.  After the loop, we could (if we wanted) actually check that we reached end of file, rather than some failure condition - I've omitted that for this simple program.